# Голосовая команда

Tags: ассемблер

Как можно реализовать голосовую команду на ассемблер.
В моей задаче нужно всего 4 команды

Comment: На ассемблере - круто.

Comment: какая платформа?

Comment: платформа PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем на ассемблере??? Не вижу смысла в наше время писать на ассемблере. На ассемблер очень редко нужно переписать очень маленький критичный к производительности участок кода в целях оптимизации. Код на языке высокого уровня понятнее человеку. Компиляторы его могут транслировать в машинный код любой платформы, а ассемблером ты привязываешься к определённой платформе.

Если ты решил реализовать голосовые команды на ассемблере, потому что ты знаешь только его (что странно), то это будет сложнее, чем изучить новый язык высокого уровня с нуля и написать на нём.

Да и вообще, такие вопросы не задают. Ты провоцируешь отвечающих сделать это за тебя. Надо задавать конкретные вопросы (а лучше сначала поискать ответ на них в Интернете).

Comment: Ладно согласен вопрос неудачно поставлен .
Есть os полностью на ассемблере (сам я ассемблер не знаю) . Задача:написать расширение с помощью которого можно было голосовой командой открыть,обновить файл 
сам же файл можно будет открыть/обновить только голосовой командой.
Как можно реализовать это.

Comment: Если ты ассемблер не знаешь, то как ты что-то напишешь на нём? Особенно голосовые команды для какой-то ОС? Там ведь нужно распознавание голоса. Это, не то, что на ассемблере, даже на высокоуровневых языках написать сложно. Что за ОС то?

Comment: Ну вообщем я как понимаю мне не написать такое , тогда тема закрыта.
А так то мне просто было интересно узнать про то как это работает.

Comment: Это неважно, на каком языке написана ОС. Вполне могут быть под нее компиляторы других, более высоких языков. 

На самом деле, в конечном счете все написано на ассемблере, потому что практически все компиляторы сначала транслируют код в ассемблер, и уже потом ассемблер переводится в машинный код.

Comment: >На самом деле, в конечном счете все написано на ассемблере, потому что практически все компиляторы сначала транслируют код в ассемблер, и уже потом ассемблер переводится в машинный код.

 Я так понимаю, то ассемблерный код - это текстовое представление машинных инструкций. Зачем компилятору нужен текстовое представление? Он может сразу переводить в машинный код, а из него уже переводить в ассемблерный, если нужно сгенерировать ассемблерный листинг. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Ну так из машинного кода восстановить ассемблерный не так просто. Но реально многие компиляторы (например, gcc) сначала генерируют ассемблер-код и передают его ассемблеру.